# Advise to buy compact camera with fast auto-focus

Tags: equipment-recommendation, camera-recommendation

Hi I'm looking for a camera for around or under 400$. I composed a list of priorities for me and hope that you could help me decide on what to buy:

### 1. Priority:

- It should be a compact camera - about the size or smaller than an RX100-II
- Fast auto-focus. One of the main motivations for the new camera is to make some pictures of my to be born child ;)
- Either a burst mode or a at least 4 fps in normal operation.

### 2. Priority

- The chip/objective should allow for low light intensity picutres. I normally prefer to take pictures without flash. Therefore I'm looking for a big (for a compact camera) chip with a descend aperture.

### 3. Priority

- I'm looking for a minimum of 16 MP and it would be great to also have access to the RAW images
- A decent video function whereby 720p is more than enough. Whereby the p is more important to me than the resolution.

### 4. Priority

- Zoom is not so important for me. Even a fixed zoom around 28 mm would be fine.
- A few programmable buttons would be a nice to have

### 5. Priority

- Viewfinder, NFC, WiFi, Hotshoe, ... are not terribly important to me.

Thanks already in advance for your advance

Comment: Good luck in your search, but this is not a shopping advice site. Vendors like Amazon and B&H offer product reviews and their sites have filters that make it easy to plug in your criteria and narrow your search.

Comment: @Caleb. I'm sorry I should have checked this first I thought that this would be OK due to similar questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might want to review cameras with phase detection AF specifically.

Fujifilm has been using phase detection in their cameras for quite long already. Recent camera X30 and XQ1 uses PDAF too. 12MP is very close to 16 MP and does not really waste any usefule detail in this case as the sensor format is relatively small.

Fujifilm X70 has fixed focal length objective and has PDAF too but is more expensive.

Canon EOS-M2 with 22mm F2 objective is probably the best option, it has PDAF too.

You may check AF perfomance on [this site](http://www.imaging-resource.com/PRODS/fuji-x30/fuji-x30A6.HTM).

Comment: Thanks for the run down. I really have to check out the X70, because it looks quite need. Same goes for the Canon EOS-M2.